# How to optimize the cost of AWS glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Well I have been working around with AWS Glue and what I am conerning is that the Cost.

The expenses for `crawler` and `job` are very cheap but the cost of `Endpoint` is very high.

If you have any tips or advices to reduce the cost please help me.

My main reason of using AWS glue is to move data from 1 database (mySQL) to another database (PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using developer endpoints, you could start to develop your glue jobs locally. This saved us all the endpoint costs. This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container/) helps you to set up everything locally.

Comment: Be very careful , delete the endpoint after use , it doesn't timeout and will just be charged for as long as its available.

Comment: My answer literally says: "INSTEAD of using developer endpoints..."

Comment: My apologise I misread you answer